# Absolute values on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Two related questions:

a) is there some characterization of all the absolute values on $\mathbb{R}$? (similar to Ostrowski for $\mathbb{Q}$)

b) are there non Archimedean absolute values on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: They are sort of untenable. Namely, you can essentially extend any absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ to one on $\mathbb{Q}(T)$ by assinging $T$ any value you want. Thus, there are tons on there. Now, $\mathbb{R}$ looks like an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\{T_i\}_{i\in I})$ for $I$ an uncountable set. Think about how many valuations there are. Also, as the above shows, there are certainly non-archimedean ones.